# Why InitializeComponent() taking long time?

Tags: wpf

How to identify which component taking long time to load. I'm using wpf window with DevExpress control. I want to know which dxcontrol taking long time to load

Thanks

Comment: if it in vs, Just `pause` and see where it got stuck.

Comment: Which devexpress controls are you using @Dinesh

Comment: am using Cardview, Gridcontrols and ButtonEdit Controls